# Where to find all hidden layers/effects in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, layers

In the QGIS there is a set of some "special" words that one can type in the 'Coordinate' box to supply additional layers into the Layers Panel or provoke extra activities. There was also [a tweet](https://twitter.com/undertheraedar/status/1191385406509637632?s=20) posted several years ago, however, it does not include all of the possible tricks.

This is the "magic" 'Coordinate' field:
[image: input]
where I can type some words, e.g. `world`
[image: input_world]

For instance, when I type `world` I am going to get this layer
[image: world]

When I type `contributors` I am receiving another layer
[image: contributors]

When I use `hackfests` it leads to this layer
[image: hackfests]

There are also tricks with `dizzy` and `bored` when typing in the 'Coordinate' field.

The content of some layers I can find under the `C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/resources/data`.

However, I was wondering how to get all available hidden features/actions within the 'Coordinate' field?

Comment: Like you, I was not aware of the Easter eggs term in computer software. It seems when I posted my answer, some users did not like it because they want to keep these words secret. However, since you have a high reputation - (> 10,000) - you can see a list of all the possible words in my deleted answer. Actually, I deleted the answer to keep these words secret as intended to be, but visible to users with high reputations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're "[Easter eggs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(media))" and they're there mainly for fun, although some of them actually provide users with useful stuff/info.

The best documentation you can find out there of those Easter eggs is **the source code itself**, since it'll be always up-to-date. After all, according to [their definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(media)#Software), Easter eggs are not supposed to be documented :)

> In computer software, Easter eggs are secret responses that occur as a
> result of an undocumented set of commands.

---

*Note: I prefer not to list the Easter eggs here, since they have to be reserved for very curious people :P.*

Comment: Thank you for a new (for me) term in computer software :)